# How can I produce the representation of data as it looked over time from multiple tables that change over time?

Tags: sql

I have several tables that contain attributes about an entity. The entity has an ID that is common to all of the tables. Each table has an effective and end date. When attributes change, a new row is inserted with an effective date of now and the previous row for that entity has its end date set to now. Previously we have only been interested in what the current state of the world is, so joining the attribute tables on the common entity ID and end date is null. We use left joins in case there are no attributes in the table, we just want NULLS there.

I would like to create a history table that contains every combination of attributes that were valid for a given entity. Here's a simplified example:

### attribute_a

| entity_id | attribute_value | effective_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 2023-03-01 | NULL |

### attribute_b

| entity_id | attribute_value | effective_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bar | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-15 |
| 1 | Baz | 2023-03-15 | NULL |

My query to return the current state of the entity would result in:

### current

| entity_id | attribute_a_value | attribute_b_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | Baz |

The result I would like to see is:

### result

| entity_id | attribute_a_value | attribute_b_value | effective_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | NULL | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-05 |
| 1 | Foo | Bar | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-15 |
| 1 | Foo | Baz | 2023-03-15 | NULL |

What the best way to approach this?

Comment: Which dbms is this ?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is to get the first row, So if The effective date is `attribute_a.effictive` date and `end_date` is the smallest `effective_date` from `attribute_b`, then you can do it as follows :

```
with cte as (
  select a.entity_id as entity_id, a.attribute_value as attribute_a_value, b.attribute_value as attribute_b_value, b.effective_date, b.end_date, a.effective_date as effective_a_date
  from attribute_a a
  inner join attribute_b b on a.entity_id = b.entity_id
)
select entity_id, MAX(attribute_a_value) as attribute_a_value, NULL as attribute_b_value, MIN(effective_a_date) as effective_date, MIN(effective_date) as end_date
from cte
group by entity_id
UNION ALL
select entity_id, attribute_a_value, attribute_b_value, effective_date, end_date
from cte
```